# Encouraging Question Askers to Read the 'Questions with similar titles' list

Tags: discussion

Having been on here for a while I find myself wanting to say 'I think we've done that before' from time to time.

I wondered whether people aren't spending enough time on the 'Questions with similar titles' list... and are a bit over ready to just post up the same topic again ?

And if so: is there any technical solution ?

Comment: I can't imagine a technical solution that doesn't either involve being annoying to emphasize the other questions or improving the related questions list. I always take a peek at the related questions list, but it's not as helpful here as on Stack Overflow where at least half the time I find a related question, which may or may not actually solve my particular problem.

Comment: If people are asking duplicate questions, they should be closed as such. I think we tend to have clusters of closely related questions, which IMHO is a good thing because it leads to thorough exploration of a topic and deep understanding.

Comment: @PatrickMcElhaney Yeah, on UX I see relatively few *exact* duplicates but a fair amount of related questions; I don't really see this as a problem. I guess it's in part because asking the same question (how do I do this form) can be so very different because of the users/type of application, but they're still different enough to warrant different answers and thus different questions.